# How to pause a script at the place I really want to?

Tags: autohotkey

I have a script say **script1** that imported many functions from other scripts. say **func1()**, **func2()** and **func3()** for example. I would like to pause the script when an entire function is completed.

Which means usually if I pause **script1** normally when **func1()** is executing, the script will pause when some line of **func1()** is completed. Now I want to guarantee the pause happens after **func1()** has finished execution.

Is there any possible way to achieve this? Particularly, is there any way I can detect which line of **script1** is executing now and add a line of code like "Pause On" after it?

Comment: Can you give an example of this?  I'm only 50% sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been thinking about nesting functions, but that doesn't work either. Can't you just add a Pause call right after the orginal code where you called the function? So not INSIDE the Function, but right after where you called the function.

In AutoHotKey (right click, [OPEN]) you can go to [View], [Lines most recently executed]. Run the script until it pauses, then hit F5 to see which lines were executed before the pause.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I did it in the similar way: with a interruption handling function globally accessible and a function call at the end of each function (inside the function), a key press (like pause) will change the value of a pre-defined variable (like pauseFlag) and the function can check the variable to determine whether to pause the script. Thank you and sorry for replying so late.